# Jump out of range

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, tasm

I am working on an assembly project regarding my university exam. It is a scientific calculator application using Tasm 4.1 on 8086 processor.

The problem I am facing is a jump being out of range. I tried to find a solution on the internet and tried multiple ways to handle it but none of them worked.

Lastly when I tried to put .386 in my program it did solve the problem but now I am facing calculation problem in my addition, so please help me solve this...

Here is my code.

```
  PRINT MACRO MSG
  LEA DX,MSG
  MOV AH,09H
  INT 21H
  ENDM     

  READ MACRO N,J1,J2
  J1: MOV AH,01H
  INT 21H
  CMP AL,0DH
  JE J2
  SUB AL,30H
  MOV BL,AL
  MOV AX,N
  MOV DX,0AH
  MUL DX
  XOR BH,BH
  ADD AX,BX
  MOV N,AX
  JMP J1
  J2: NOP
  ENDM     

  PRINTMUL MACRO N1,L2,L3
  MOV BX,000AH
  MOV AX,N1
  XOR CX,CX 

  L2: XOR DX,DX
  DIV BX
  PUSH DX
  INC CX
  CMP AX,0000H
  JNE L2      
  L3: POP DX
  ADD DL,30H
  MOV AH,02H
  INT 21H
  LOOP L3
  ENDM  


  intro macro
  print msg1
  nw_line
  print msg2
  nw_line
  print msg3
  nw_line
  print msg4
  endm

  nw_line macro
  mov dl,0ah
  mov ah,02
  int 21h
  endm

  addm macro
  PRINT MS
  READ N,U1,U2

  PRINT MT 
  READ M,G1,G2 

  PRINT ANS 
  MOV AX,N       
  ADD M,Ax

  PRINTMUL AX,H1,J5 
  endm

  square macro
  endm

  cube macro

  endm

  divm macro

  endm

  kill macro
  mov ah,4ch
  int 21h
  endm

  .model large
  .stack 100h
  .data
  wrg db 13,10,"Wrong Choice ","$"
  ch0 db 'Press Keys for the below Operations:$'
  ch1 DB 13,10,"1 For Addition ","$"
  ch2 DB 13,10,"2 For Subtraction ","$"
  ch3 DB 13,10,"3 For Multiplication ","$"
  ch4 DB 13,10,"4 For Division ","$"
  ch5 DB 13,10,"5 For Square of a Number ","$"
  ch6 DB 13,10,"6 For Cube of a Number ","$"
  choice db ?
  msg1 db ' ___________________________________________________$'
  msg2 db '|            Scientific Calculator               |$'
  msg3 db '|    By kABIR kHAN & Muneeb Ur Rehman        |$'
  msg4 db '|___________________________________________________|$'
  MS DB 13,10,"INPUT FIRST NUMBER: ","$"
  MT DB 13,10,"INPUT SECOND NUMBER: ","$"  
  MF DB 13,10,"INPUT NUMBER: ","$"
  ANS DB 10,13,"RESULT IS : $"
  N DW ?
  M DW ?
  .code
  start:
  mov ax,@data
  mov ds,ax

  intro
  nw_line
  nw_line
  print ch0
  print ch1

  print ch2
  print ch3

  print ch4
  print ch5
  print ch6
  nw_line

  mov ah,01
  int 21h
  mov choice,al

  nw_line
  cmp choice,31h
  je addition

  cmp choice,32h
  je subtraction

  cmp choice,33h
  je multi

  cmp choice,34h
  je division

  cmp choice,35h
  je squ


  cmp choice,36h
  jmp cue


  addition:
  addm
  loop addition

  subtraction:
  loop subtraction

  multi:
  loop multi

  division:
  divm
  loop division

  squ:
  square
  loop squ

  cue:
  cube
  loop cue


  kill
  end start
```

Comment: _"but now i am facing calculation problem in my addition"_ You're going to have to be more specific than that when you describe your problem.

Comment: Where did you put `.386`? Make sure it is after `.model`, or even after `.code` directives, the dot-something directives in TASM are simplified pre-configured variants of full directives, and they work well together only when used in expected order (but then they work well and save you some typing which would be required with full directives). "I am facing calculation problem" ... if it is runtime problem producing unexpected values, use debugger to single step the code and figure out why those unexpected values emerged. `.386` on wrong spot will produce machine code for 32b mode, not 16b.

Comment: You can of course always work around that relative jump problem by making the code shorter/more modular using more sub-routines and making the conditional jumps over shorter range, or in worst case jump with inverted condition over regular longer `jmp` instruction targetting the original conditional jump label, which will cause the conditional jump to be only +3B over the long jump = no problem with range (but it's ugly to read, so if you are free to use 286/386 extensions, rather use them, 8086 is somewhat limited). BTW for a calculator app the `.model small` should be enough (~100x enough).

Comment: well the addition problem is that it is not giving me correct answer to the addition just because i add .386 and i added it just after .model